# Views: How to list "files" view for their own files?

Tags: views, files, workbench

I'm working on Workbench module on Drupal 7. There is a "File List" tab and showing all images and files from the site. I would like to change this to be showing their uploaded files only.

PS: the "File List" Tab is from the "workbench_files" Views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open the workbench file tab, then from the contextual menu on the right select edit view.
[image]

Add the relationship 'The user that uploaded the file.' if it does not already exist.
Above Relationship, you will see Contextual Filters (these are dynamic contextual parameters you pass to views). Add a contextual filter 'The User ID' and set the relationship to 'User who Uploaded'.

[image]

In the same window just below that there is a section 'When the filter value is not in the URL'. You select 'Provide default value'. This opens a select list, from which you choose 'Use ID from logged in user'

[image]

Comment: sorry, it still not working by adding that relationship and filter :(

Comment: My bad. You should add the filter as a contextual filter, and in the section : 'when the filter value is not in the url' tick provide default value and select 'User ID from logged in user'.

Comment: I dont see "when the filter value is not in the url" on Contextual Filter section

Comment: that works. Thank you J. Reynolds. Is there a way to show the image thumbnail? Now right, it only show the file type icon on my field:Mime type.

Comment: For that you have to add a field (if it is not already present) 'File:rendered' and select the appropriate File View Mode. Then go to admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/file-display and set the display on that file view mode (be careful not to touch Preview as it is used in the media browser also)

Comment: I enabled the "Rendered file" display on "configureation > file types > Manage file display > Default" and still didnt see "file:rendered" on Views. Maybe something im missing.